# Give role by clicking on a button (This interaction failed)

Tags: button, discord.js, roles, discord-buttons

So i have made an embed with 1 button under it and if you click that button you would supposed to get the role but in Discord it is saying "This interaction failed". I want to only have members with Manage Webhooks to do the command to let the bot send the embed and that everyone can use the button. I get no error in Visual Studio Code.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ComponentType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    category: "command",
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('nda')
        .setDescription('Make the NDA embed + button for the role!')
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageWebhooks),
    async execute(client, interaction) {

        const ndaRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('1099050320660799609');

        const ndaChannel = client.channels.cache.get('1145302828408111125');

        var ndaEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Instant Editing Staff NDA')
            .setColor('#e00c45')
            .addFields(
                { name: '**1. __ Disclaimers__**', value: '...' },
                { name: '...', value: '...' },
                ...;

                

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("nda")
                .setLabel("Confirm That You Have Read The NDA")
                .setEmoji("1099073509692543068")
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
        );

        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
            componentType: ComponentType.Button
        });

        interaction.reply({ content: "I have posted the NDA embed!", ephemeral: true });
        await ndaChannel.send({ embeds: [ndaEmbed], components: [row] });

        collector.on("collect", async (interactionButton) => {

            let id = interactionButton.customId;
            let userID = interactionButton.user.id;

            let userData = interactionButton.guild.members.cache.get(userID);

            var message = "";

            switch (id) {
                case "nda":
                    userData.roles.cache.has(ndaRole.id)
                        ? message = `You already have the ${ndaRole} role!`

                        : await userData.roles.add(ndaRole).then(() => {
                            message = `You now have the ${ndaRole} role!`;
                        })

                    return interactionButton.reply({ content: `${message}`, ephemeral: true });
            }

        });
    },
};
```

I don't know what to change.

Answer (score 2):

The code is trying to reply before the message which says you have the role is set. Which means that it is trying to send a message which does not have any content in it, which discord doesn't accept and cancels the reply.

Putting the `interactionButton.reply` in the function passed in the `.then` method would help. A better way to approach this is by awaiting the `userData.roles.add()`